# Angular5 / Typescript - function is there but gone when try to call within a function

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I am importing D3 in my component. Then I need to assign a layout to the `D3.layout`-property. The problem is, that my D3-Object knows the `layout`-property when I output it in the console, but the function is unknown when I try to call it.

what could that be?

```
import { adjacencyMatrixLayout } from './lib/d3-adjacency-matrix-layout';
import * as d3Lib from 'd3';

export class AdjacencyComponent implements OnInit {
  public adjacencyData: any;
  private _d3 = d3Lib;

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
    console.log(this._d3); // <--- layout is there, I can see it in the console
    this._d3.layout; // <---- Property 'layout' does not exist on type 'typeof ?? WHY? 
  }
}
```

Comment: What types have you added to provide type information for `d3`? I suspect you either haven't added the type definition, or it contains an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need the type definitions for D3.

You can install the NPM Package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem, the solution was to assign `d3Lib` inside the constructor.